# How to use foreach loop in an array object variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

I have declared `array` `object` variable which is `ordered_items` and it seems to be fine. But now how can I retrieve every item inside the object variable using `foreach loop` in javascript. Thanks in advance.

```
        var ordered_items = [];

        for(var x = 0; x < prev_tbl_rows.length; x++){

            var product = $(prev_tbl_rows[x]).find("td.one_prod_name").text();
            var quantity = $(prev_tbl_rows[x]).find("td.one_qty").text();
            var price = $(prev_tbl_rows[x]).find("td.oneprice").text();
            var subtotal = $(prev_tbl_rows[x]).find("td.oneSubtotal").text();

            ordered_items.push({
                product: product,
                quantity: quantity,
                price: price,
                subtotal: subtotal,
            });

        }

        console.log(ordered_items);

       //I don't have an idea how to retrieve each item inside this variable /*ordered_items*/
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve]

Comment: You can pretty much copy your existing loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
let ordered_items = [];
$("someSelectorForPrevRows").each(function() {
  $row = $(this);
  ordered_items.push({
    product: $row.find("td.one_prod_name").text(),
    quantity: +$row.find("td.one_qty").text(),
    price: +$row.find("td.oneprice").text(),
    subtotal: +$row.find("td.oneSubtotal").text()
  })
})
ordered_items.forEach(item => console.log(item.product, item.quantity, item.price, item.subtotal)
```